# Bootstrap accordion issue with arrow

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, accordion

I'm working on an accordion and as part of it, I have to put an arrow at the right side of each collapse. Unfortunately, I can't see it but it is still there. I don't know if there any style issues or not. Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?

I have attached my code there. Please go through it.

**HTML**

```
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5>
        <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#nb-accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h5>
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#nb-accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
      <h5>
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#nb-accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
.nb-accordion {

    .card-header {
        background: #333;
        padding: 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #3E3E3E;
        border-radius: 0 !important;
    }

    .card {
        display: block;
        background-color: #fdf03b;
        border-radius: 0;
        color: #333;
        border: none;
    }


    .btn {
        display:block;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        border-radius: 0;
        padding: 20px;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: left;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;

        &::after {
            content: '';
            display: inline-block;
            background: url(../images/downwards-pointer.svg) no-repeat;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;         
            right: 10px;            
            bottom: 0;          
            left: auto;         
            margin: auto;           
            height: 20px;           
            width: 20px;            
            z-index: 50;
        }

    }

    .card-body {
        display: block;
        padding: 20px;
    }

}
```

[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/q1m8kujp/)

Answer (score 0):

i think because your svg location

```
.nb-accordion {

    .card-header {
        background: #333;
        padding: 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #3E3E3E;
        border-radius: 0 !important;
    }

    .card {
        display: block;
        background-color: #fdf03b;
        border-radius: 0;
        color: #333;
        border: none;
    }


    .btn {
        display:block;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        border-radius: 0;
        padding: 20px;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: left;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;

        &::after {
            content: '';
            display: inline-block;
            background: url(../images/downwards-pointer.svg) no-repeat;  //HERE
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;         
            right: 10px;            
            bottom: 0;          
            left: auto;         
            margin: auto;           
            height: 20px;           
            width: 20px;            
            z-index: 50;
        }

    }

    .card-body {
        display: block;
        padding: 20px;
    }


}
```

Comment: Hi Andrel Sitanggang, can we see the image if the location is wrong? And I tried as you said. But didn't work. Thanks bro :)

Comment: Hello Danish, you can't see the image. It depends on your folder tree or your file type.

Answer (score 0):

Open image `svg` file in text editor and copy the code and write as below.

```
background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='30' height='30'><circle cx='15' cy='15' r='10' /></svg>")  no-repeat;
```

I hope this will works!

Answer (score 0):

Add wrap `.nb-accordion` and `.card-header` add `position: relative;`

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/NOwxaL?editors=1100)

```css
.nb-accordion .card-header {
  background: #333;
  padding: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #3E3E3E;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  position: relative;
}
.nb-accordion .card {
  display: block;
  background-color: #fdf03b;
  border-radius: 0;
  color: #333;
  border: none;
}
.nb-accordion .btn {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
.nb-accordion .btn::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  background: url(https://cdns.iconmonstr.com/wp-content/assets/preview/2017/240/iconmonstr-arrow-65.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: auto;
  margin: auto;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  z-index: 50;
}
.nb-accordion .card-body {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  
<div class="nb-accordion">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5>
        <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#nb-accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h5>
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#nb-accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
      <h5>
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#nb-accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```